# How to change Jquery terminal cursor shape? I want it to be '|' not a block

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-terminal

How to change Jquery Terminal cursor shape ?
I have tried messing with the CSS described here 
http://terminal.jcubic.pl/css/jquery.terminal.css
But I could only change the color not the shape!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use border-left to simulate bar cursor like this:

```
.terminal .inverted, .cmd .inverted, .cmd .cursor.blink {
  color: #aaa;
  border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
  background-color: black;
  margin-left: -1px;
}
@keyframes terminal-blink {
  0%, 100% {
      border-left-color: #aaa;
  }
  50% {
      border-left-color: #000;
  }
}
```

here is [demo](https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/NRaAWg) with prefix animation for other browsers.

**EDIT**
Right now you can use css variable `--animation: terminal-bar;` to enable bar cursor.